# Not able to use Array.from

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5

I am using a platform that only supports ECMAScript 5, and therefore my JavaScript code must work within that limit.
Randomize is just a helper function I’ve written. This code snippet works perfectly in an environment that supports never versions than ecmascript 5, but it does not work in an ecmascript 5 environment. The function Array.find does not exist in ecmascript 5. How can I make it work in Ecmascript5?

Thanks in advance!

This is the code:

```
Array.from(crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(16))).map(randomize).join(‘’)
```

Comment: Use a polyfill? Should be pretty simple.

Comment: What platform is it that supports the `crypto` api but not ES6?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#polyfill

Answer (score 0):

Since u can not use the function,i think u can rewrite a period of code of function that can help u reach the same condition.
here are my private method from other developers:

```
function arrayFrom (){
         let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
         return args
};

arrayFrom(1,2,3)// printf: [1,2,3]
```